# Nunit and code coverage for C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, nunit

I am using C# + .Net 4.0 + VSTS 2010. I am wondering whether Nunit is the best and easy to learn unit test tool for this platform (C# + .Net 4.0 + VSTS 2010)? If yes, I want to learn basics of Nunit, and also want to find how to generate code coverage report based on Nunit result (e.g. code coverage report to show which function is tested, which function is not tested, how many lines are tested.)

Any recommended tutorials for Nunit and code coverage for a newbie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sent this tutorial on NUnit for beginners to some juniors I work with

http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/NUnit-Tutorials.aspx

also coverage is something I wouldn't quite worry about for now until you get to grips with unit testing. There are more things involved in unit testing like dependency injection and mocking frameworks to make sure that code gets covered and is testable.

personally id work on integration and unit testing first and then move in coverage - just my 2 cents

hope it helps

paul

Comment: Thanks Paul! I see the tutorial is about Nunit, could you also recommend some coverage reporting tutorials to me?

Comment: may be useful to look at NCover (its not free) but has a good section on how to get started with code coverage http://docs.ncover.com/how-to/getting-started-with-code-coverage/

Comment: Hi Paul, I read the nunit tutorial you recommended to me. I find it is just a general introduction, and what I want to learn is a tutorial which is step-by-step guide to tell me how to nunit to do unit test for some specific code samples. Any recommendations? Thanks.

Comment: ill help you if you want - my mail address is paulstack [at] hotmail [dot] com - mail me what you want to do and ill help you out :)

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks in advance. I want to learn by myself and save your time. Appreciate if you could recommend me a step-by-step tutorial for nunit. :-)

Comment: if you can afford it buy a book called 'The Art of Unit Testing' http://amzn.to/9q2DZl - otherwise try this out - http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011905-1.aspx - its very difficult to suggest things for this. the book will 100% help as its fantastic. Never feel as though you would be wasting my time. We all need help to get in the right direction :)

Comment: glad the question was answered - you have my mail address if you need anything - paul

Answer (score 2):

for code coverage you can use ncover, there is a nice integration into VS that is called testdriven.net. 
If you are on VS 2010 you might also want to check the builtin test framework (MSTest) that also has coverage builtin

hope it helps

Comment: Cool, could you recommend a tutorial for ncover for a newbie like me?

Comment: oops, sorry. Didn't meant to send just that :). I'd skip the command line section of how loading the xml into the report explorer, as this is quite simple when using testdriven.net. Also, note that if you use the VS 2010 integrated one you can see the highlighted code directly on VS, oposed as ncover that opens a different program.

Comment: Thanks! I find the getting started guide is very helpful. I also want to learn nunit, and could you recommend a step-by-step guide to tell me how to nunit to do unit test for some specific code samples? Thanks.

Comment: NCover is now a commercial product. OpenCover is an open source replacement https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover

Answer (score 2):

#### Unit Tests with Coverage in C#

I know that things have changed somewhat since the OP, but [coverlet](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet) is free, is used in the [ms tutorial for C# unit test code coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage?tabs=windows), and supports nunit, xunit, and mstest.
Basic instructions are to add the package to your C# test project:

`dotnet add package coverlet.collector`

and then run tests with a flag:

`dotnet test --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"`

#### Maybe Off-topic VSCode Coverage Display Plugin Instructions

VSCode [coverage-gutters](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryanluker.vscode-coverage-gutters) can be used to consume the output.  It colorizes your source code as a way to show coverage results.

It looks like coverlet generates a file called "coverage.cobertura.xml", so you just need to add it to the list of coverage files to look for.  In settings.json add the following setting:

`"coverage-gutters.coverageFileNames": ["coverage.cobertura.xml"],`

And run the "Coverage Gutters: Watch" command.

Comment: warning: with these instructions, a new coverage file is created each time you run tests and my vscode setup with gutters will combine them all (so if run tests, delete a test, and then rerun, it will still show up with the original coverage).  I'm sure that can be fixed, but I don't have time to look into it right now.

Answer (score 1):

The company that makes ReSharper (JetBrains) now has their own coverage tool called [dotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/). As of now, I think dotcover and Resharper combined are less expensive than ncover.